# Wordpress - Change Admin / Login URL

Tags: php, wordpress, url, wp-admin

first of all - sorry for my bad english. Im trying to change the Backend-URL from `/wp-admin/` to `/admin/` as example.

im using

```
define('WP_ADMIN_DIR', "admin");
define( 'ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', SITECOOKIEPATH . WP_ADMIN_DIR);

add_filter('site_url',  'wpadmin_filter', 10, 3);
function wpadmin_filter( $url, $path, $orig_scheme ) {
$old  = array( "/(wp-admin)/");
$admin_dir = WP_ADMIN_DIR;
$new  = array($admin_dir);
return preg_replace( $old, $new, $url, 1);
}
```

and for .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^admin/(.*) wp-admin/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Well, this went fine for me two days ago. But since today its not working anymore.

Wordpress is logging me out after im going for `xxxx.xx/admin/`.

Cant even Login because of redirects(?). The Login-form is just resetting.
j4i: i despair.. ive looked up any related thread on stackoverflow
Thanks for any help or advice in advance,

Angelos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well. i fixed it.

```
define('WP_ADMIN_DIR', "admin");
define( 'ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', SITECOOKIEPATH . WP_ADMIN_DIR);
```

this entry has to be in `wp-config.php`.

Ive wrote it in my plugin and obviously its not working.

thanks anyway <3

Comment: Note that it can't be just placed anywhere in the `wp-config.php`, but should be below the inclusion of `wp-settings.php` because `SITECOOKIEPATH` is set somehwere in there.

Answer (score 1):

**Add constant to wp-confing.php**

`define('WP_ADMIN_DIR', 'admin');
define( 'ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', SITECOOKIEPATH . WP_ADMIN_DIR);`

**Please see URL will help you.**

`[https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-change-the-admin-url-or-wp-admin-to-secure-login/][1]`